# No output or error message from Erlang shell

Tags: erlang, erlang-shell

Sometimes when i try to run a command in the Erlang shell (for example calling a function from a module etc) the shell doesn't give any output or error message and just returns. I am sure that i give the command in the right shape (with a dot at the end etc).
To solve this i have to give the following commands in the shell:

```
'. or ".
```

And then the shell prints a long atom or what ever and then after that i can run my original command correctly.
Does anyone have seen a same issue? And what is the reason for this?

Comment: If there is a answer which solves your problem, accept it by clicking  on the check box outline to the left of the answer. This will adding their reputation which encourages people to give answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like there were an initial `'` or `"` in the command line. So the shell is waiting for the second `'` or `"` which closes the atom or string declaration. It prints the evaluation result and is now ready for the next command.

Look at this example in the console (started with `erl`):

```erlang
Eshell V10.6.2  (abort with ^G)
1> io:format("Hello world!").
Hello world!ok
2> io:format("Hello world!             ).
2> ".
* 2: syntax error before: '.'
```